# remove the index values while converting excel file to text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using python 3.7 and I wanted to convert `.xlsx` file into `.txt` file and below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe1 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\path\exceldata1.xlsx', index=False)

print(dataframe1)

with open(r'C:\path\exceldata1.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    dataframe1.to_string(text_file)
```

I am able to convert `.xlsx` into `.txt` but I am also getting the index value printed in the text file. I want to remove that.

```
0     9100499S    1
1     9100099S   10
2     910000SW    1
3     91Y961SR    5
4     9120301S   20
```

above is the text file created but I do not need the index values in the first column.

and i also wanted to separate the two column values by tab to make it into a TVS text file so that they do not come in one cell..How do i go about it??

```
9100499S   1
9100099S   10
910000SW   1
91Y961SR   5
9120301S   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `index = False` to your `to_string` call will prevent the index from being included.

If you want tab separated values, instead of `to_string` you should use `to_csv` - this function is meant to generate comma separated values, but you can change what character is used as a separator by adding `sep='\t'` to get tab separated values instead.

Comment: Could you also answer the next part of my question which i updated